# How to launch firefox app from c# in ubuntu

Tags: c#, .net-core

c-sharpers, I am trying to use "System.Diagnostics.Process" to open the firefox app, but can't figure it out in ubuntu 20.04

main.cs

```
 using var process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName="/lib/firefox/firefox.sh";
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.Start();
```

After the execution of the code above, nothing happens no error no dust ??

Comment: I am using ubuntu with .Net core

Comment: Why are you trying to do it this way?  Is this for testing?  If so, you might have better luck using an api like Selenium and then using the Firefox driver.  You can find Firefox examples here: https://www.browserstack.com/guide/run-selenium-tests-using-firefox-driver and .net core Selenium example here: https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/how-to-ui-test-using-selenium-and-net-core-on-windows-ubuntu-and-maybe-macos

Comment: Well am doing a c# workshop where I have to manage multiple processes, so I trying to create a process like opening firefox or any other app with c#

Comment: are you sure that "/lib/firefox/firefox.sh" is the correct path? in debian it usually is "/usr/bin/firefox". also, where do you run that from? console? you should get some kind of output there. did you check processes with `ps`?

Comment: firefox.sh exist in /lib/ and also in /usr/lib/ , if he can't find the file why there is no errors in the console ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I found is to add "Thread.sleep()" .

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using var process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName="/usr/lib/firefox/firefox.sh";
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
```